# List<object> memory overhead

Tags: c#, memory-management

I have something like this:

```
List<object> res = new List<object>();
...
while (...)
{
   byte[] val = //get new byte[4]
   res.Add(val); //if this is commented memory usage goes from 2Gb to 180Mb
}

return res;
```

Now `val` is always byte[4] and there are around 37000000 elements. So I would think that `res` should be around 37*10^6 * 4 bytes =  148 MB, but the real memory usage is around 2GB. If I comment `res.Add(val);` then memory usage is somewhere 100 MB.

So where does the memory go to?

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

I've tried to use uint instead of byte[4], but the result is the same:
[image]

**EDIT2**

Ok, using uint instead of byte[4] ***and*** `List<uint>()` instead of `List<object>` put the memory to around 300 MB.

Comment: How do you calculate memory-usage? Task-manager?

Comment: 2 GB for 37 million objects comes down to 54 bytes per boxed value, including the bookkeeping of the runtime (GC) and the overhead of .NET in general, and your program isn't small, as you indicate a footprint of 100 MB when it's doing absolutely nothing. Why do you think the `List<T>` is relevant? Doesn't an array display the same behavior? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Using VS debugger, see the screenshots

Comment: @CodeCaster I just tried to use `new object[37000000];` instead of `List<object>` - with uncommented it's still 2 Gb and with commented it's 420 Mb

Comment: Something simple to try: `List<byte>` and `AddRange`. (Don't forget to initialize the list with some realistic size).

Comment: @CodeCaster It's just that I don't get why the difference is so high, ok I could understand maybe 4 times more memory, but 54 bytes instead of 4 feels like something's wrong... Also that spike of memory in the end, maybe you could explain it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a common problem of allocating large amounts of tiny objects: object overhead, which you can usually disregard, comes into play.

> 37*10^6 * 4 bytes = 148 Mb

Assuming that an array of four bytes would occupy four bytes in memory is incorrect. In addition to the payload of four bytes, array object must store array's length, a sync block, and a type pointer. This works out to 12 bytes of overhead on a 32-bit system, or 24 bytes on a 64-bit system.

In addition to individual overheads of array objects you need to factor in the overhead of memory allocator, overhead of memory alignment, and overhead of garbage collector. All things taken together, it is not unreasonable to see the total memory in use grow to 2 Gb.

One way to fix this is to switch to a list of `uint`s, which do occupy four bytes each. When you need to store four bytes, convert them to `uint`, and store it in the list. When you need your bytes back, convert `uint` into a temporary four-byte array. Use [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1184xdy4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to deal with converting between `uint`s and arrays of `byte`s.

Comment: Hm, surprisingly, this didn't decrease memory, I've put a screenshot in the question

Comment: @ren Do you use `List<object>` or `List<uint>`? List of objects would carry overhead of "boxing" the value, which is close to the overhead of an array. The overhead of list of `uint`s is a lot smaller.