# Why is a List of objects (containing of string-properties) about 8 times bigger (bytes) than the corresponding textfile?

Tags: c#, parsing, memory, streamreader

I have a textfile (or csv) which looks like this:

```
this is line 1 and I consist of my words
this is line 2 and I consist of my words
...
this is line 500k (not exaggerating)
```

Now imagine we have 500.000 lines of text.
The file´s size is around 69.337 KB.

When I read it line-by-line (with BufferedStream - StreamReader.ReadLine()) and translate it into a List of according objects (with properties for each word), the List grows to a size of around 520 MB (in Memory).

Why is that?

Code:

```
while (reader.ReadDataRow(row, false))
            {
              if (reader.CurrentObj!= null)
              {
                _myDataset.Add(reader.CurrentObj);
              }
            }
```

CAUTION: The textfile is an EXAMPLE, since it is completely irrelevant, what exactly those words are.

I just want to have a better understanding on what is happening.

Comment: How large is it if you load a `List<string>` with `File.ReadLines(path).ToList()`. How do you measure it at all?

Comment: Well, you say it's a "list of objects" but you haven't given us any sample code showing us what that object looks like. If you could provide a [mcve] we can point out where all the overhead comes from. (There will be several places, so it's not worth trying to list them all without a concrete example.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List<object> memory overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43229348/listobject-memory-overhead)

Comment: Yes it was still in edit while you wrote (which must have been lightning-fast)

Comment: You also mention its holding properties for each word - surely depending on the properties you could be having a lot of data per word.

Comment: Tim Schmelter I am looking on the right side under "diagnostic tools" - process memory as well as in taskmanager

Comment: BugFinder: On average, an object does have a size of about 144Bytes.
I guess there is some overhead, the raw data is much smaller

Comment: @ArnoNym If you want to reply to someone you should put an `@` before their name so they will be notified.

Comment: 500k lines with 10 words in each line will produce 5 million string references (4 bytes each) and will consume 25MB just for keeping the references (we are not talking about any data at this point)

Comment: Juharr: Sorry and thanks
@BugFinder: The object consists of 15 Strings and 1 DateTime

Comment: @SirRufo: Wow, that sure is a lot! How does one solve this issue? Is my approach fundamentally wrong or is there a solution like only processing chunks of data or something?

Comment: You are using a `DataTable`/`DataTable` not a `List<T>`. That always has to box/unbox objects to and from value types like `DateTime`(around twice the memory of the original value type).

Comment: It depends on what kind of problem you are going to solve. From this small piece of code/description noone can decide how you should work with that data. If you can process the data in chunks, well do it - if not, you maybe need a local database where you can persist the data/states during processing

Comment: Well hopefully some words are reused, so you have less entries right?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Wrong, it is a List<MyObject>.
Maybe the naming of my objects and method (ReadDataRow) is confusing